# How to find out if the script is running in Linux or OSX

Tags: linux, shell-script, osx, snmp

I want to write a bash script to get some information of Switches through snmpbulkwalk. I would like to use the same script in Linux and OSX environments, so I want to know if there is a way to do a compatible version that identifies the current OS, get the needed SNMP packages for each one and run a bunch of commands.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Like `uname` ? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: That's right! I completely forgot about the `uname`... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, `uname` will display the generic name of the operating system.

My roommate has the latest (I think) version of OSX, and it displays `Darwin` when it runs.

If you'd like more of an output, `uname -a` will give you the kernel version, OS version, and a bunch of other information, in addition to the generic name.

That said, this doesn't always properly fingerprint an OS. My CentOS VPS displays Linux, or GNU/Linux, depending on what I run.

I'm also just a college student who does this kind of stuff for fun (/ on my development server), so there may be a better answer to this.

Comment: For telling Linux from OS X, `uname` alone will work. If you want to fingerprint a specific Linux distro, or if you expect to actually run on something from the OpenDarwin/PureDarwin family and need to tell that apart from OS X, you'd need a more sophisticated tool.